# Exim4 server setup and configuration with remote SMTP

Tags: php, linux, email, smtp, exim

I am trying to setup exim4 server with remote SMTP server.
Here is my configuration for Exim4.

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames='test.com'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1;'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='true'
dc_relay_nets='*'
dc_smarthost='remote smtp ip'(it is valid)
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='true'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

Now when i execute php mail script it gives following error.

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<test@gmail.com>:
host <valid host> [valid host]: 550 #5.1.0 Address rejected.
```

In exim log there is following error

```
  2015-08-18 18:39:03 1ZRh6V-0008Dm-DF <= root@exim-server U=root P=local S=39648
  2015-08-18 18:39:03 1ZRh6V-0008Dm-DF ** root@exim-server: Unrouteable address
  2015-08-18 18:39:04 1ZRh6W-0008Ds-2y <= <> R=1ZRh6V-0008Dm-DF U=Debian-exim P=local S=40449
  2015-08-18 18:39:04 1ZRh6W-0008Ds-2y ** root@exim-server: Unrouteable address
  2015-08-18 18:39:04 1ZRh6W-0008Ds-2y Frozen (delivery error message)
```

Can anyone help to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some outer IPs to the `dc_local_interfaces`. Now exim hasn't legal way to communicate with other MTAs.

Comment: Thank you Kondybas for you reply. I have add outer ip in dc_local_interfaces but it is not working.